# Can anyone explain why should we finalize an object?

Tags: java, final

private static final  SecureRandom no = new SecureRandom();
Why should we finalize no  in here ??

Comment: Finalize or mark a variable as final?

Comment: Note that a finaliser is a rarely used (and generally unwise to use) method that us called when an object is garbage collected

Comment: Note `finalize` is a method on `Object` and `final` is a keyword would means the reference to the SecureRandom cannot be changed.